# How to get all the photos_stream photos in my facebook account by using API?

Tags: django

In my Django projects I need to get all the photos inside photostream by using facebook API?,Now i used the api just like https://graph.facebook.com/10151509108346729/photos/?access_token="68051_10151509108346729_1731694342".but I got only the shared photos.

Comment: I guess you have to do authentication in order to get private photos, oauth works with FB. what API wrapper are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
  facebook_images=[]
           user = request.user
           details = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=request.user,provider='facebook').order_by('-id')[0]
           uid = details.uid
           access_token = details.extra_data['access_token']
           url = "https://graph.facebook.com/%s/albums?fields=id&access_token=%s" % (uid,access_token)
           url = str(url)
           data = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
           album_ids = []
           if data.has_key('data'):
               for x in data['data']:
                   album_ids.append(x['id'])
           for album_id in album_ids:
               url="https://graph.facebook.com/%s/photos?access_token=%s" %(album_id,access_token)
               photos_response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
               data = photos_response['data']
               photo_urls = []
               for x in data:
                   facebook_images.append(x['source'])
           request.session['facebook_images']=facebook_images
           if request.session['print_type'] == 'photobook':
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('photobook_photo_selection'))
           elif request.session['print_type'] == 'canvas':
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('canvas_photo_selection'))
           else:
               return redirect('photo_selection')
```